# Match the User Name against the Security EventLog

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to take a domain user and for it want to check the Security Event Logs for say Logon and then Print the events which match but it returns me null value:

```psh
Get-EventLog -Log Security -Computer PC1 -InstanceID 4624 -After(Get-Date).AddDays(-2) | ? {
  $_.Message -match "Account Name:\s+qasimali\s" -and
  $_.Message -match 'Logon Type:\s+(2|10)\s"
}
```

but it generates no data for output

> Read-Host : name cannot be Null or Empty.

Whereas command runs and gives no error. I just want to check whether this command is running fine or not.

Comment: If the above command doesn't return any matches (`$null` if you assign the result to a variable), the given user hasen't logged in locally or via RDP on PC1 in the last 2 days. I don't understand the question.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers : Sir but when I cahck the EventLogs manually there a number of events against this specific user !! Need help please

Comment: Are the entries actually from PC1, from the last 2 days, and do they actually contain that particular username and logon type? What happens if you leave out the event ID (`Get-EventLog -Log Security -Computer PC1 -After (Get-Date).AddDays(-2)`)? Do you get records then? Do they have the event ID 4624?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers : Yes Sir from Logs there are entries for ID 4624 when I run The Code    Get-EventLog -Log Security -Computer PC1 -After (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)

Comment: These are of differnet types like 4624, 4634,5145,4672 etc

Comment: Yes Sir exactly 4624

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post, or use a free image hoster like [TinyPic](http://tinypic.com/).

Comment: Still It says you need 10 reputation to upload pictures.
I swear there are Logs which are with the ID 4624. :(

Comment: Host the images like ansgar said and post some links. We can do the rest while you have >10 rep

Comment: http://i58.tinypic.com/2i0u911.jpg

Comment: http://i57.tinypic.com/b483de.jpg

Comment: It's rather curious that selecting a particular instance ID shouldn't work, while a query without that restriction would show results with that exact instance ID. Well, be that as it may, even if `-InstanceId` doesn't work for some reason, you can still restrict the results by adding the condition `-and $_.EventId -eq 4624` to your filter (`? {...}`).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers  Sir Instance ID is working, If I only run this code if show all the logs  Get-EventLog -Log Security -Computer PC1 -InstanceID 4624 -After(Get-Date).AddDays(-2) Issue is with matching the "Account name " with user name , I also tried Replacementstrings[1] and [5], still it dd not work. Since yesterday you really made me learn Powershell to some extent, but Ias I am very young in this field will need your guide and help to make this script, Regards

Comment: I just notice that the string in your second condition starts with a single quote, but ends with a double quote. Is that a typo in your question? If so, we're back to square one: the user qasimali did not log into PC1 locally or via RDP in the past 2 days. Please provide evidence to the contrary.

Comment: Sir I applied both ' logon type:\s+(2|10)\S)' AND ALSO WITH " "but neither woked. It is not showing any error..even I tried both strings seperately, still it didnot work. I am assuming to covert it into xml and then extract targetusername and compare with username. But I am curious why about code is not working. !

Comment: `\s` matches *any* kind of whitespace, not just spaces, and `\S` (uppercase S) is the opposite of that (matches anything that is *not* whitespace). Please double check your expressions.

Answer (score 2):

The way I have done this in the past is as follows ( Thoroughly Commented for clarity) :

```
## Set Username Input
$UserInput = "DOMAINUSER"

## Set date in past to retrieve events up to
$StartTime = ((Get-Date).AddMinutes(-2))

##Set Domain Controller to search on
$ComputerName = "DC1"

## Retrieve Event 4624 from DC Eveng Logs
$Logons = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $ComputerName -FilterHashTable @{LogName="Security"; ID="4624"; StartTime=$StartTime;EndTime=(Get-Date)}

## Initialize variable to store outputs in
$EventOutput = @()

## Enumerate Events to retrieve usernames to compare against User Input
foreach ($Logon in $Logons) {
    ## Convert Event to XML
    $LogonXML = [XML]$Logon.ToXML()

    ## Retrieve Username from XML Object
    $LogonUser = (($LogonXML.Event.EventData.Data | Select "#text")[5])."#text"

    ## Retrieve Logon Type from XML Object
    $LogonType = (($LogonXML.Event.EventData.Data | Select "#text")[8])."#text"

    ## Check Event Username matches User Input
    if ($LogonUser -match $UserInput) {
        ## Check LogonType is correct
        if ($LogonType -eq 2 -or $LogonType -eq 10) {
            ## Append Event Object to Event Output
            $EventOutput += $Logon
        }
    }
}

## Output Resulting Event Output Object
$EventOutput
```

The Resulting Output can be manipulated to retrieve whatever details you wish. I find converting each Object to XML to parse further values useful.

**NOTE** : I've just thrown this together quickly from memory, this can be quickly restructured to enable other queries if required. Start and End Times will need to be changed to extract information from the correct timespan.

Comment: Dear I am thankful for your input. Actually I want to check for each domain users if his event Log was logon then to print the out put,but in my code I am not sure where my condition is applied correctly or not.. I am unable to understand How..Please any Help

Comment: Apologies, I may have misunderstood your question initially. Taking another look, you mention "but it Generates an error as Read-Host : name cannot be Null or Empty." Do you not wish instead to "Write-Host $Logons"?

Comment: Also, I have just noticed "$-.Message -match "Account Name:\s+qasimali\s" " should be "$_.Message -match "Account Name:\s+qasimali\s"

Comment: Oh..that was just a writing mistake ._message !

Comment: Brother May be my logic or Syntax is Wrong. Actually I want to take a user for that user I want to check each security log and take  out that logs that was for that user meeting the requirement that logon type shoud be 2 or 10..help please

Comment: I've edited my answer above to take into account your Logon Type requirement. Generally I find that splitting out your one-liner into specific steps enables you to work your way to the correct answer. Once you have the correct output, you can condense your command to a one-liner if you wish.

Comment: Bro can you add this in my code as it is hard for me compile your code my my other part of the code, please

Comment: Unfortunately I find that quite hard to believe . The answer I have provided can easily be converted into a function to be run at any point in your script. You simply need to provide it the correct inputs.

Comment: how do i get the date into a variable aswell?